# Which package name is correct?

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, android-studio, kotlin

Is this a problem at all . Just launched an app from a company named let's say ABC technologies limited . This is the official name of the company and Also the name on playstore . However the domain name of the company is abctech.com . so we went ahead to name the package name of the app com.abctech.appname . my question is . When giving an app name . Is it supposed to be com.domainname.appname or com.companyname.appname . I kinda have mild anxiety and honestly when i realized this I've been kinda worried . Is the package naming supposed to be the domain name or the company name because most explanations online didnt specify which. Did I make a mistake . Is this something to worry about . Is this an issue at all .

Comment: It really doesn't matter much.  This is just convention.  The main thing is to be consistent.  If you already have code doing it one way, either keep doing that or change the way you do it throughout your code.  The point of naming things like this is to avoid collisions between your code and code you get elsewhere.  As long as the two names you're considering are equally unlikely to be chosen by another company, you're fine either way.  If one is more likely to be used by someone else, use the other one.

Comment: If you're still on the fence after what I say above, choose the shorter name to save wear and tear on your company's keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to be your domain name in reverse. So if your website was `www.foo.org`, your package name should be `org.foo.appname` (in case you were wondering where the "com" comes from). This is so it won't have any chance of overlapping with anyone else's package name, because presumably there can only be one owner of a domain name.

But to the best of my knowledge, no one is policing this and there are no rules. I have old apps on Google Play with packages named after a domain I no longer own.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say "should".  Using your company's domain name is simple and obvious, so it's usually a good way to go.  But there is definitely nobody policing this.  It isn't about tying the code to your company's domain name.  Any naming scheme that avoids collisions with code written elsewhere is equally acceptable.  In fact, if you're writing code you think you might some day want to publish as open source, your company might prefer that you leave their name out of it.

Comment: Using your company's domain name *is* the convention though: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html So unless you have reason not to do that, you might as well follow convention! No need to complicate things - if you ever *did* want to release the code, you'd just change the package name before you release it (along with other sanitation, like renaming classes and variables and editing comments where necessary). No point worrying about trying to come up with a future-proofed package name, especially if you're already anxious about it. Conventions help you move on!